# How would i program a selenium script to press on buttons located in a discord message by a bot?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, discord, message

I cannot find the correct element to use for a path since the text of a button in a specific message doesn't provide the path to the newest message in the chatbox, when i run it just finds the old message (where i got the element copied from) and clicks on that. I need the bot to first locate the newest message in the chatbox (i think) then click on a button (''U1'') which will automatically send a new message in the chat it then needs to find the former new message (containing "U1" button) and look for U2 button and so on untill U1 untill U4 are clicked on that specific message. All suggestions on improvement off the set up is also highly appreciated.(i could not find a bot that already does something like this)

def wait_for_u1_button(driver):
u1_button_xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'message-2qRu38') and .//button[contains(@class, 'component-ifCTxY') and contains(., 'U1')]]"
try:
u1_button_message_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, u1_button_xpath)))
return u1_button_message_element
except TimeoutException:
print("U1 button not found")
return None

i created this function but it can't locate the U1 button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium interacts with Browsers. So if you are looking to interact with Discord Application, then it is not easily implacable. You can login into Discord in your browser. You will have to manage the login or create script to open your existing browser. Take your approach after considering this.

Comment: I might not have been clear on that. I am actually already running the script in a browser. Chrome to be specific.